# How to get SSH public key for Github in windows10

Tags: github, ssh

I followed the steps below, but I couldn't find the right key.

```
1. open command prompt (CMD)
2. enter SSH-keygen and press enter
3. press enter to all settings. now your key is saved in c:\\Users.ssh\\id_rsa.pub
```

Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, TrueLove. SO is a place where programmers help programmers make source code work. This question is not about source code and is off-topic as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help. Please delete the question here and ask in a forum where it can be on-topic; perhaps https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing CMD command, do the following.

```
WIN key → Apps & features → optional features → Install open SSH client
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wow4m.png)
[image]

Comment: I installed it.
After that, should I proceed with the previous work?

Comment: Yes. If there is something wrong, please contact me again.

Comment: Okay, I succeeded in getting the ssh key. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a notable exception that in Windows 10, using the described route only wrote the files to the folder if the file names where not specified in the ssh-keygen generator.

giving a custom key name caused the files containing the RSA public and private keys not to be written to the folder.

Open the windows command line
Type ssh-keygen
Leave file name blank, just press return,
Set your passphrase
Generate your key files. They will now exist. and be stored in c:/Users/YourUserName/.ssh/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).